# Finding Distance from Parabola to Directrix & Focus

Tags: conic-sections

I have a parabola that has a focus at $F(0,f),f>0 $ with vertex at $V(0,0).$ If there is a point on the parabola with parametrization $ P(x(t),y(t))$ where $t$ is the parameter, how far is $P$ from $F$ and how far is $P$ from the directrix in terms of $t$ ?

Comment: These may help http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parabola.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Answer (score 0):

In general if the eqation of parabola is y^2=4ax,
the distance of any point (x1,y1) from directrix is( x1+a)
In your case eqation of the parabola is x^2=4ty as focus is (0,t)
Thus distance of (x,y) from the directrix is (t+y)

Comment: Can you please improve this answer by formatting it using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?